# Return JSON Response without constructing one

Tags: json, rest, jax-rs

Assuming I have proper POJO class, here is my post method:

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response createProductInJSON(Product product) {

    String result = "Product created : " + product;
    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

}
```

which returns some string. You know, for example in GET method, if you send an instance of the POJO class it sends a JSON string instead. I want to know if this is valid for Response. The output should  be something like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 201
    },
    "data": {
        "message": "Congratz."
    }
}
```

Is there a shortcut for this or do I have to implement a simple JSON constructor code?

Comment: this migh help -[link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)

Comment: Are you actually creating a resource or just transforming? If you are sending back a 201, you should also be sending back a URL in the ```Location``` header, and you should be able to then GET that resource.